# i am getting error on running this this test but if i write "await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.reverted" only then this test passes

Tags: solidity, ether, unittesting

i am getting error in this unit test but if i write test with to.be.reverted only it passes ?

```
await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.reverted
```

```
describe("fund", async function() {
        it("fails if we dont send enough eth", async () => {
            await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
                "You need to spend more eth"
            )
        })
    })
```

Comment: What is the error message... ?

Comment: Can you show the code for `fund`?